Logical error in a simple banking system program in C
So, when the user deposit an amount on the account(struct), the balance does not get updated and thus I can't proceed with other operations like withdrawing etc.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct bank_account
{
    int account_number;
    char name[15];
    char surname[15];
    float balance;
};

void deposit(struct bank_account, float);
void withdraw(struct bank_account, float);
void check_balance(struct bank_account);


int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
    
// initialization of bank account with default values

    struct bank_account account; 
    account.account_number = 1234567;
    strcpy(account.name, "Randy");
    strcpy(account.surname, "Orton");
    account.balance = 0;

    int choice;
    float amount;

    printf("Welcome to our Bank's environment!\n");
    printf("Account number: %d\n", account.account_number);

    // Menu for banking operations
    do
    {
        printf("\nMenu:\n");
        printf("1. Deposit\n");
        printf("2. Withdraw\n");
        printf("3. Check balance\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the amount to deposit: ");
            scanf("%f", &amount);
            deposit(account, amount);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter the amount to withdraw: ");
            scanf("%f", &amount);
            withdraw(account, amount);
            break;
        case 3:
            check_balance(account);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Thank you for your preference.\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choise! Please try again.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    while(choice != 4);

    return 0;
}

// Function to deposit money into the account
void deposit(struct bank_account account, float amount)
{
   account.balance += amount;
   printf("Deposit succesfull! Current balance: %.2f\n", account.balance);
}

// Function to withdraw money from the account
void withdraw(struct bank_account account, float amount)
{
    if(amount > account.balance) 
        printf("Insufficient balance. Cannot procceed with withdraw.\n");
    else 
    {
        account.balance -= amount;
        printf("Withdraw succesfull! Current balance: %.2f\n", account.balance);
    }
}

// Function to check account balance
void check_balance(struct bank_account account)
{
    printf("Current balance: %.2f\n", account.balance);
} 

I gave it to chat gpt and said that inside the function parenthesis I need to incorprate a pointer to struct and not the struct itself as well as this operator "->" (which I didn't know about) within the functions to access structure members, instead of the dot that I use.
I ask it if I can somehow make it without the -> operator but it cannot give me a clear answer.
So what do you think? Is there another way or I must use pointers and the "->"?

Aside: you didn't use argv in int main(int argc, char **argv[]) which is just as well because it should be int main(int argc, char *argv[]), or int main(int argc, char **argv).

... or just int main(void) - Turn on more compiler warnings and fix all warnings.

You pass the bank_account structure object by value to your functions. That means the functions get a copy of the structure object. Any modifications the functions do are done only to the copy, not the original object. To solve the problem you need to emulate passing references to the structure object, using the pointer-to operator & and having the functions take pointers as arguments.

Aside: function prototypes that only declare the argument types are syntactically valid, but provide minimal help to the caller, because they lack meaningful argument names. For example if there are two arguments of the same type, which is which?

"... or I must use pointers and the "->"?" - yes

Another aside: why are you using float? Never use float without a clear reason why you cannot use double, the natural floating point type in C. In a banking app the float is incapable of accurately representing sums >= 167772.17.

@WeatherVane, using floating point numbers at all may in fact be a mistake in such a scenario.

In your deposit function you are passing the struct by value. A copy is made, you modify that copy, and then there is no impact on the original. You need to pass pointers to your structs.
E.g.
void deposit(struct bank_account *account, float amount)
{
   account->balance += amount;
   printf("Deposit succesfull! Current balance: %.2f\n", account->balance);
} 

Your other functions will need to incorporate this as well if they're modifying a bank_account struct.
As a sidenote, initializing a struct can be much less verbose than you've made it.

    struct bank_account account; 
    account.account_number = 1234567;
    strcpy(account.name, "Randy");
    strcpy(account.surname, "Orton");
    account.balance = 0;


Can equivalently be written:
    struct bank_account account = { 
        1234567,
        "Randy",
        "Orton",
        0
    };

The trailing zero is not strictly necessary, but you may wish to be explicit.
